# there is a problem with embedding an HTML template in which there is a loop. Django

Tags: python, html, django

Good afternoon to all! I'm new to Python and Django. There is a page on it I am trying to attach a template of another page via include, but the loop that should display the data does not start. help me figure out the problem.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}
  
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="container">
    <h1>График замен ФН</h1>
    <style>
        {
        font-size: 12px; /* Adjust the font size as needed */
      }
    </style>

        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Применить фильтры</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>


    {% include "includes/fn_base_template.html" with fn_replacements_page=fn_replacements_page %}

    {% include "includes/paginator.html" with fn_replacements_page=fn_replacements_page %}

{% endblock %}
```

includes/fn_base_template.html

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-md-2">Название объекта</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">SAP</th>
        <th class="col-md-2">Юридическое лицо</th>
        <th class="col-md-2">Адрес объекта</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">Номер позиции</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">Модель ФР</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">Серийный номер ФР</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">Серийный номер ФН</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">Дата первичной регистрации</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">Дата замены</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-body">
      {% for fn_replacement in fn_replacements_page %}
        <tr>
          <td class="table-body-cell">{{ fn_replacement.name_object }}</td>
          <td class="table-body-cell">{{ fn_replacement.sap }}</td>
          <td class="table-body-cell">{{ fn_replacement.legal_entity }}</td>
          <td class="table-body-cell">{{ fn_replacement.addres_object }}</td>
          <td class="table-body-cell">{{ fn_replacement.nomer_pos }}</td>
          <td class="table-body-cell">{{ fn_replacement.model_fr }}</td>
          <td class="table-body-cell">{{ fn_replacement.sn_fr }}</td>
          <td class="table-body-cell">{{ fn_replacement.sn_fn }}</td>
          <td class="table-body-cell">{{ fn_replacement.date_fp }}</td>
          <td class="table-body-cell">{{ fn_replacement.replacement_date }}</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Separate page includes/fn_base_template.html it starts and works normally.
It will be required to work with this block on several pages , so I 'm trying to achieve operability

Comment: Code seems file, please share the views too for identify the issue. It would be helpful if you can check is the list object is empty or not by printing {{fn_replacements_page }} on html